# Alternative to java.nio.file.Paths in Java6

Tags: java, android, javafx, classloader

Since the java.nio.file.Paths class and its package do not exist in Java6 and Android, I was wondering how I could use an alternative method for `Paths.get("filename").toUri().toURL()`? I try to load a `fxml` file using the `FXMLLoader` in JavaFX. Usually I put all fxml-files in a specific layout-package within the src directory, which makes it easy to load these files via relative path. However, because I build the JavaFX project for Android, I need to store the fxml-file into the `assets` directory so that it will automatically included in the apk file (using gradle build).

**This is my project structure so far:**

```
MyProject
-- src\main\java\somepackage\Main.java
-- assets\sample_layout.fxml
```

**However, when I build the apk, the structure looks like this:**

```
Content of MyProject.apk
-- assets\sample_layout.fxml
-- classes.dex // which contains all compiled classes
   -- somepackage\Main.java
```

I need to access the `sample_layout.fxml` within the `assets` directory from the `Main.java`. Any idea how I can do that?

**Here is what is working on Java7, but not for Java6** (and not on Android since the Paths class is not available in Java6):

```
URL myFxmlLayout= Paths.get("assets/sample_layout.fxml").toUri().toURL();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(myFxmlLayout);
AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
```

**For Java6 I tried the following, which is not working:**

```
URL myFxmlLayout= new URI("file:///assets/sample_layout.fxml").toURL();
// OR
URL myFxmlLayout= new URI("file:///../../../../assets/sample_layout.fxml").toURL();
```

Hope you can help me.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the usage of Paths was design-technically wrong to begin with. The FXML source might better be packed in a jar as a read-only resource.

```
MyProject
-- src\main\java\somepackage\Main.java
-- src\main\resources\assets\sample_layout.fxml

URL myFxmlLayout= Main.class.getResource("/assets/sample_layout.fxml");
```

In your original design, you could use `new File(...)` instead, but then have to take care of the path to `assets` (`getAbsolutePath`), and the runtime installation of it.

Comment: Great! works like a charm on my Android device :) However, it does not work at my desktop since it can not find the fxml file from that directory. Any idea how to make it running on both, Android and the desktop? I thought about providing two paths, one for the Android device and one for the desktop version and then check which file can be found.

Comment: Nevermind. The easy way was to use `src/main/resources` as `Source Folder` within eclipse. Then you can use the layout from `src\main\resources\assets\sample_layout.fxml` to run it on Desktop and it is still working when building it for Android :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
new File(filename).toURI().toURL()
```

I haven't ever worked with JavaFX and Android, so I haven't tested this in the context you describe, but it is the pre-`java.nio` version of the `Paths.get(...)` idiom you use.

Comment: Hey James, this works running the project locally as JavaFX project (Note: that `new File(filename).toURL()` would be the correct way but is deprecated, so it works the same way as Paths.get(...) in Java7). However, it can be build without errors but it does not run on Android so far, since it does not exept the relative path I've tried :-/ I think `../../assets/sample_layout.fxml` should be the correct path, but it does not work. Any idea? Any suggestion for the file path according to the apk-structure listed in my question? Thanks in advance.